# Focal points for the exponential map and Jacobi fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

It is known that in a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, if there is a closed geodesic and a non-zero, periodic, non-constant Jacobi field along it, then M has a focal point. Is the converse true? That is if $(M,g)$ has a focal point, then does there exist a closed geodesic and a non-zero, periodic, non-constant Jacobi field along it? If it is not true in general, what extra conditions on $(M,g)$ would imply the statement?